# recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view) returns point zero in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a strange case with UIPanGestureRecognizer in Swift.
I have a function that handles the pan gestures, and specifying "false" in UIGestureRecognizerDelegate such that no other gesture interferes with the Pan.

Here's the problematic case:

1. User touches with 1 finger and starts to pan
2. User puts a second finger on the screen - The second finger is ignored
3. The user lifts the first finger while the second is still touching - At this moment my handler gets called with 
   `recognizer.state == .ended`.  The problem is that the location at this moment (which I get by calling `recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)`, returns the point `(0,0)`

Am I using the wrong way to get the point? It seems that since the second finger gets totally ignored, the first finger should behave as a regular pan, and I'll get the location when the state==ended.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested it - locations are no longer available when the recognizer is ended (using the following)

```
  recognizer.location(ofTouch: 0, in: recognizer.view)
```

I would add a variable that tracks the last known point in .began & .changed (I get data back in those) then use that data in .ended

EDIT: Getting the data out with subclassing

```
class pgr: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    var myTouch:Set<UITouch>!

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        myTouch = touches
        super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event)
    }

}
```

Then back in your implementation

```
    if sender.state == .ended {
        print(sender.myTouch.first?.location(in: sender.view))
    }
```

Comment: Is it documented that they are not available? I used what you said as a workaround, but I wonder if that's the best practice

Comment: If you check UIGestureRecognizer, the two being discussed are the only ways to get that info (there is no touches: Set<UITouch> that I could find access to - i think that belongs to the UIView. There may be a slicker way to do it that I am not aware of however.

Comment: UIView will give you the info in its own override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) , but it doesn't seem to get called if another gesture is successful.

Comment: Actually, I was looking at some code - if you subclass the gesture recognizer and override   override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) { it looks like it should work, will test it and update my answer in a min